# how to calculate polynom coefficient at compile time?

Tags: c++, polynomials, newtons-method

I need to calculate the initial guess for the newtons method at compile-time. I'd like to prevent this calculation from happening at runtime.

Usually, I'd solve this problem using the enum trick:

```
enum
{
  a = make_coeff(...),
  b = make_coeff(...),
  c = make_coeff(...)
};
```

where a, b, c are coefficients and `make_coeff()` is a consteval/constexpr function. I can't use this approach this time, because the coefficients are of class type.

I have tried:

```
static constexpr coeff_type a[]{make_coeff(...), make_coeff(...), make_coeff(...)};
```

Would such an array of coefficients guarantee that `make_coeff()` will not be executed at runtime? Even though `make_coeff()` is marked consteval, gcc will happily generate code for it. But clang will not allow even a static constexpr array.

the errors clang gives are:

```
error: static variable not permitted in a constexpr function
error: cannot take address of consteval function 'make_coeff' outside of an immediate invocation
```

gcc is happy, but I am suspicious of what it is actually doing.

another thing I was thinking about is:

```
template <auto C>
constexpr auto coeff() noexcept
{
  return C;
}

coeff<make_coeff(...)>();
```

since I can pass a coefficient as a non-type template parameter.

is a template array possible?

```
template <auto ...C>
decltype((C, ...)) const a[]{C...};
```

perhaps even something like:

```
template <std::size_t I, auto ...C>
auto get() noexcept
{
  // ... easy to implement, but I'm not sure if it is worthwhile
}
```

Comment: Making the variable constexpr forces its initialization to occur at compile-time. If Clang doesn't like consteval, try a constexpr function.

Comment: I'm not so sure, I think there's some leeway given to the compiler as to what to do. This is why I prefer the enum trick whenever I can use it.

Comment: Perhaps the standard says so, but I don't think I've seen compilers behave otherwise. You can always check the result on https://gcc.godbolt.org to be sure.

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee anything anything at all to happen at compile time. It doesn't guarantee there is a compiler to begin with.

Comment: If you can create a boolean expression with one or more coefficients, you could put it in a `static_assert` and have a compile time error if it's not evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @n.m true, it allows an interpreter, hence everything would be forced to happen at runtime.